# ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64

Tags: macports

I am trying to compile a program. It requires netcdf (which I downloaded with macports) and it is in fortran. I tried using -m32 in case it was a problem with the 64 vs 32 bit version, but it did not change anything. This is the full error message:

```
call_mcd.F:6095:40:

       call pbl_parameters(1,dimlevs,ps,pplev,z_0,
                                    1
Warning: Rank mismatch in argument ‘ps’ at (1) (rank-1 and scalar)
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_nf_close_", referenced from:
      _loadeof_ in ccfshvBk.o
      _opend_ in ccfshvBk.o
      _mola_ in ccN2zoJZ.o
  "_nf_get_var_int2_", referenced from:
      _mola_ in ccN2zoJZ.o
  "_nf_get_var_real_", referenced from:
      _loadvar_ in ccfshvBk.o
      _loadeof_ in ccfshvBk.o
      _getsd_3d_ in ccfshvBk.o
      _getsd_2d_ in ccfshvBk.o
      _get_3d_ in ccfshvBk.o
      _get_2d_ in ccfshvBk.o
      _heights_ in ccN2zoJZ.o
      ...
  "_nf_inq_varid_", referenced from:
      _loadvar_ in ccfshvBk.o
      _loadeof_ in ccfshvBk.o
      _getsd_3d_ in ccfshvBk.o
      _getsd_2d_ in ccfshvBk.o
      _get_3d_ in ccfshvBk.o
      _get_2d_ in ccfshvBk.o
      _mola_ in ccN2zoJZ.o
      ...
  "_nf_open_", referenced from:
      _loadeof_ in ccfshvBk.o
      _opend_ in ccfshvBk.o
      _mola_ in ccN2zoJZ.o
      _heights_ in ccN2zoJZ.o
  "_nf_strerror_", referenced from:
      _loadeof_ in ccfshvBk.o
      _getsd_3d_ in ccfshvBk.o
      _getsd_2d_ in ccfshvBk.o
      _get_3d_ in ccfshvBk.o
      _get_2d_ in ccfshvBk.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Does anyone have an idea on what I can do? 
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

As commented above, Macports *does not* install libraries to the same locations as an install from source. You need to include `/opt/local/include` to link the header files and `/opt/local/lib` to link the compiled binaries *assuming that your Macports install directories are still standard*.

I'd recommend running
`locate libnetcdff.dylib`
and 
`locate netcdf.h`
to ensure that these files are where you expect them.

The compilation command would then be
`gfortran -fsecond-underscore -I/opt/local/include test_ncdf.f90 -o test_ncdf -L/opt/local/lib -lnetcdff` for a program called `test_ncdf`.

*Note the second f in `-lnetcdff`*

Comment: This! `Note the second f in -lnetcdff` solved it for me.

Answer (score 0):

Posting since I don't have enough points to comment:

Some things to try:

Make sure you have the netcdf lib in on the link line when you compile your program.

Did macports put the library in /opt/local/lib? if so, is /opt/local/lib on your search path?

You can verify that the lib actually contains those symbols (_nf_open_ et al) using the nm tool.

```
nm -g name_of_netcdf_lib
```

Did the macports distribution include the ncdump tool? does it run w/o error?